# Last iteration of loop not completely executed

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently writing a short script to scrape all outlets from a retailer in my home country. I first scrape all possible postal codes from the website of the postal service, after which I enter these one by one automatically with Selenium in their location finder. After this, I check whether the found locations are already in my result DataFrame and I add the ones that I did not find yet. Here is the code I used:

```
# Define options and webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation" :2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path", options=options)


# Get postal codes

driver.get("website post office")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
postal_codes = [code.string for code in soup.find_all("tag", class_="class")]


# Get retail location

driver.get("retail website url")

option1_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option1_button)

option2_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option2_button)

outlets = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Name","Address"])

for i in range(len(postal_codes)):
    searchbar  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"xpath")
    searchbar.clear()
    searchbar.send_keys(postal_codes[i])
    searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    names = [name.strong.string for name in soup.find_all("div", class_="class")]
    addresses = [address.div.string for address in soup.find_all("div", class_="class")]

    for j in range(len(addresses)):
        if addresses[j] in outlets["Address"].values:
            print(addresses[j] + " added already")
        else:
            outlets = outlets.append({"Name": names[j],"Address": addresses[j]}, ignore_index=True)
```

I am managing to scrape all of the locations except for the last postal code. The script perfectly manipulates the location finder to open up the retail locations for all postal codes except for the last one in the postal_code list.
For this last postal code in the postal_code list, it opens up the webpage correctly and enters the correct postal code, but does not seem to register the addresses and the names for the outlets. When I open up the addresses list and the names list, they still contain the elements of the postal code before the last one. It seems like the loop is not entirely completing. Can someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, it's actually for banking, I already fixed the parameters and gave in a sample postal code ("9000").
https://www.kbc.be/particulieren/nl/kantoor.html?q=9000&_charset_=UTF-8&filter%5B%5D=KBC_PALO&filter%5B%5D=CBC_PALO

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        params = {
            'q': '9000',
            'filter': [
                 'KBC_PALO',
                 'CBC_PALO',
            ],
            'language': 'nl',
        }
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['branches'])
        print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.kbc.be/X9Y-P/elasticsearch-service/api/v3/branches/search')
```

Output:

```
  branchId                    branchName  ...           saturdayOH cashCd
0  ORG7441          KBC BANK GENT KOUTER  ...  N;09.00.00;12.00.00      2
1  ORG7426       KBC BANK GENT DE STERRE  ...  N;09.00.00;12.00.00      2
2  ORG6304     KBC BANK GENT GRAVENSTEEN  ...                  NaN      3
3  ORG3225  KBC BANK GENT WATERSPORTBAAN  ...  N;09.00.00;12.00.00      3
4  ORG7446           KBC BANK GENTBRUGGE  ...                  NaN      3
5  ORG7447            KBC BANK WONDELGEM  ...                  NaN      3
6  ORG7434           KBC BANK ZWIJNAARDE  ...                  NaN      3
7  ORG7439           KBC BANK MARIAKERKE  ...                  NaN      1
8  ORG3407            KBC BANK OOSTAKKER  ...                  NaN      3
9  ORG3395       KBC BANK ST.-AMANDSBERG  ...  N;09.00.00;12.00.00      2

[10 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: Hi, while it does solve the problem in another way, I am specifically looking for a correction of my code and the method I am using. I am planning to apply the same code for other banks that do not offer a solution with an API. I gave you an upvote but I cannot accept your answer as the solution for this reason.